# How to disable multiline select in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

when I am selecting multiple lines in vscode with cmd+shift+arrow key as you can see in the attached photo, each line gets selected individually. How can I disable this and make the selection work normally(go to the end of each line as I move down the arrow key)?

[image]

Comment: Disable `Selection/Column Selection Mode` in the main menu.  Or there is probably a button on the taskBar (the bottom bar) where you can disable it as well.

Comment: "Column Selection Mode" is already disabled.

Comment: Is your `ctrl+shift+downArrow` bound to anything other than `cursorDownSelect`?

Comment: That was it, it was linked to `Navigate view down` -- which I saw was a "User" setting. I removed that binding, and now it works. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Mark, could you post your comment as an answer so that this can be marked as answered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern of selections in your image is exactly what I get if the `Column Selection Mode` functionality is turned on.  However, you say it is not enabled.

The next possibility to check is whether the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>downArrow</kbd> command is bound to something else other than what you expect it to be.

It is bound to `cursorDownSelect` by default and that is the behaviour you are trying to achieve.  You can check to see what else it might be bound to by going to the `Gear icon/Keyboard Shortcuts` editor, enabling the `Record Key` icon to the right of the input box.  And then type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>downArrow</kbd> to get a list of commands bound to that keybinding.

You indicated that that keybinding was indeed bound to something else by you that you could disable to get your desired behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Go to VSCode Settings(File -> Preferences -> Settings), search for the word `cursor` and then disable this option:

`editor: Multi Cursor Merge Overlapping`